# AS3 Broadcast live video using FMS and save that video for VOD

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I want to broadcast live video I am using FMS to brodacast live video.
I want to save that video to view again back, may be after some days or week.

I know how to publish live

ns.publish("appName","live");

But I want to save this video and view back when user request to see it again (not as live - as video on demand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Adobe documentation for [NetStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html). You simply use "record" instead of "live" :

```
ns.publish("lecture", "record");
```

Comment: Thank you sir,

You mean to say I can brodcast live video by using ns.publish("lecture", "record");
as well as i can playback it when I requre?

Comment: Exactly. Though you may have to customize how and where to save, with the server application.

Comment: Thank you,

I read the doc.
but still there is question in my mind.
How can I publish it live with record parameter?
I got confused can you explain me more?

With parameter "record" can it be viewed as live?

Comment: Recording module in Flash AS3, which records live stream to FMS.
want to pause recording or stop rec.
what should I write.
my code It dosent work.
private function handlePause(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 ns.pause();
}
private function handleStop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 ns.close(); 
}

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't want to replace your saved file each time...
use appned mode for publish

```
ns.publish("appName","append");
```